# Entity Framework. ADO.NET модель. Как зашифровать строку подключения в web.config?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Мне нужно зашифровать строку подключения в Web.Config.

Как это реализовывается?

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnection" connectionString="шифр" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Я использую ADO.NET модель БД, проект ASP.NET MVC 5.

В конечном итоге хочу получить `Web.Debug.config` с открытой строкой и `Web.Release.config` с закрытой.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/795135/Encrypt-ConnectionString-in-Web-Config

Comment: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/connection-string-encryption-and-decryption/ba-p/830094

Comment: Спасибо, но нужно, чтобы было как на скриншоте.